# C++ outputs numbers backwards

Tags: c++

I am writing a program that separates an integer that has been inputted into it.  For example, 12345 would output 1 2 3 4 5 but each in it's own variable.  Right now, if I enter 12345 it gives me 5 4 3 2 1.  Can anyone help me figure out how to make it output the digits in reverse?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int number;

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter number: ";
    cin >> number;
    while (number > 0) {
        int digit = number % 10;
        number = number / 10;
        cout << digit << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: just get it into a string and print in sequence?

Comment: Hint: what value does `12345 % 10` have?

Comment: @nightcracker I understand that but I'm asking how would I get the values to print in reverse..

Answer (score 2):

You could use recursion.

```
void PrintNumber(int number)
{
    int digit = number % 10;
    number /= 10;

    if (number > 0)
        PrintNumber(number);

    cout << digit << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't store your number in an int, store it in a string instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string number;

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter number: ";
    cin >> number;
    for (int i=0; i<number.size(); i++) {
        char digit = number[i];
        cout << digit << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is still in reverse order.

Comment: @etbh What exactly does the i in brackets next to number do?

Comment: @user515430 In this case, **i** is a counter. Its value will start at 0 for the first occurrence of the loop, and increase until it reaches the value of the size of the string minus 1. (That's what this _for_ loop does.) In C++, a string behaves like an array of characters. To access the characters contained on the string, you can use the square brackets operator around the index of the desired character. The index is simply the number of the character in the string, starting by 0. So, to access the first character, you write `mystring[0]`, to access the second `mystring[1]` and so on.

Comment: @user515430 Here, the counter `i` takes as values the indices of all the characters in the string in their natural order (0 to the size of the string minus 1). That makes the expression `number[i]` return one by one as values the digits of your number in the right order.